# Scoring partial credit on multiple-response multiple answer exam questions in r

Tags: r

I am trying to grade multiple-response multiple choice exam questions using r. I want to create a separate column in my dataframe with the score. The score is given depending on how many right and wrong choices the student has made. For instance, if the right answer is given by choices A & D, and the student answered AB, the score would be +1-1+1-1+1 = 1. Essentially +1 for every right choice and -1 for every wrong choice. In this grading scheme, not choosing E when E is not correct constitutes a right choice.

Here is a sample of what my dataframe looks like:

```
 mydata <- structure(list(Student = 1:5, Question = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1"), 
                     Answer = c("A", "BC", "AD", "AC", "BD"), 
                     Key = c("AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD")),
                     .Names = c("Student", "Question", "Answer", "Key"), 
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I cannot figure how to tell r to compare the two columns ("answer" and "key"), identify letters that are either present or absent in both, assign a value to each iteration (A present in both columns, A absent from both columns, B present in both columns, and so on...), and the add those values up.

Alternatively, each separate calculation (A present in both columns, A absent from both columns, B present in both columns, and so on...) could be place in its own column, and the sum be calculated simply.

I have searched through so many posts, but cannot find similar issues. Most posts compare numeric columns and use ><= types of comparisons, which do not work for my problem.

I do appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible way to score the answer using `dplyr`:

```
> mydata %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(score = length(intersect(strsplit(Answer, '')[[1]], strsplit(Key, '')[[1]])))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Student Question Answer Key   score
  <int> <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <int>
1       1 Q1       A      AD        1
2       2 Q1       BC     AD        0
3       3 Q1       AD     AD        2
4       4 Q1       AC     AD        1
5       5 Q1       BD     AD        1
```

Here is another way that accounts for the +1/-1 for each right or wrong choice. Because there isn't a way of knowing what all the possible choices are just from the data, you will have to include that specifically.

```
all_choices <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
for(choice in all_choices) {
   mydata[ , choice] <- 1 + xor(grepl(choice, mydata$Answer), grepl(choice, mydata$Key)) * -2
}
mydata$score <- rowSums(mydata[ , all_choices])

> mydata
  Student Question Answer Key  A  B  C  D E score
1       1       Q1      A  AD  1  1  1 -1 1     3
2       2       Q1     BC  AD -1 -1 -1 -1 1    -3
3       3       Q1     AD  AD  1  1  1  1 1     5
4       4       Q1     AC  AD  1  1 -1 -1 1     1
5       5       Q1     BD  AD -1 -1  1  1 1     1
```

Comment: No need for the `dplyr::`. Just load `dplyr` beforehand, since the package is necessary for the pipe to work anyway.

Comment: I like to include it just to show specifically which functions are coming from `dplyr`. For example, `intersect` is also implemented by `dplyr`, but it isn't necessary to use that version (even though we might as well because they do the same thing in this case).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this. I love the simplicity of the code. However, it only really does half of the scoring. I am trying to score their thought process. Therefore, not picking B, for example, when B is wrong, should also earn 1 point. On a question that has 5 multiple choices, if you pick all the right choices (an none of the wrong) you can get 5 points. Does that make sense? Is it possible?

Comment: @RRL I have included an update that I think does the scoring as you requested. It's a little convoluted, so let me know if you want me to clarify anything.

Comment: @C.Braun I thought it would have to be convoluted. I just could not think of how to tell R to to the sum of scores for elements that are missing, when it does not know what is missing. I have never used xor() and your solution still seems very elegant. I figured I would have to have a column per answer choice with the score and then simply add them up, but was still struggling to translate it all into R. I cannot thank you enough for taking time to help me with this.